# Plotting data from a text file

Tags: qt, plot, waveform, qfile

This question is a bit long and complicated. I have a text file containing parameter values of a waveform and need to plot the wave using these values. A typical waveform is shown below[image]

I am able to search for the files using the code below;

```
void MainWindow::on_SearchFiles_clicked()
{
    QString fileName1 = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,tr("Open Text File"), "", tr("Text Files (*.txt)"));
         QFile file1(fileName1);
         if(!file1.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
             return;

         QTextStream in(&file1);
         while(!in.atEnd()){
             QString line = in.readLine();
         }
}
```

Now my question is how to plot a waveform using the values in the file chosen. A typical text file is shown below

[image]

Also how can I read the values of the other parameters from the text file and assign them accordingly in qt. i.e taking the values of frequency, gain etc and declaring them again in qt

Answer (score 1):

The header is easy: just get the index of the first `:` and split on that:

```
int index = line.indexOf(':');
QString key = line.left(index);
QString value = line.mid(index+1);
```

Then it's a if-else chain to assign them to the correct fields.

The samples themselves can be gotten from the `line.trimmed().toInt()` (or `toDouble()` in case you need decimal values)

Comment: So if I want to get the frequency value from the file I type                              `in int index = line.indexOf('Frequency');
         QString key = line.left(index);
         QString value = line.mid(index+1)`

Comment: It'll take a while to finish, not used to C++ but thanks. I'm on the right path.